# Deploy ASP.NET MVC App on IIS Express or an other WebServer?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, localhost

Is there any possibility deploying and runing an ASP.NET MVC 5 App locally on an **IIS Express** or on an other WebServer **without establish the normal IIS**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following link describes the necessary steps hosting an ASP.NET MVC project with IIS Express:

[Running a Site using IIS Express from the Command Line](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/using-iis-express/running-iis-express-from-the-command-line)

Answer (score 0):

Referer the following links, might be helpfull. :)

[Deploying to iis](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/deploying-to-iis)
[Test mvc in iis](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2011/04/22/test-you-asp-net-mvc-or-webforms-application-on-iis-7-in-30-seconds.aspx)

Comment: I do not want to use normal IIS, I want to deploy the app on an IIS Express!